# Change Button on-click only if data is successfully stored to database without postback asp.net mvc5 EF6

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

[image: Change Button without post-back after storing data successfully]

I have a situation wherein I have to change the button "Send Request" to "Request Sent". There are 'n' number of such buttons in my form and i need to change the buttons for all of them

The button should change only if data is successfully stored into the database without reloading the form. And here is how i have stored data to database.

```
public ActionResult SendRequest(string RequestId)
{
        MyRequest request = new MyRequest();
        request.UserId = loggedInUserId;
        request.FutureFriendId = RequestId;
        request.Status = RequestStatus.Pending;
        db.MyRequests.Add(request);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
}
```

Later i might want to change the button "Request Sent" to "Cancel Request" to rollback the operation. Please give me a solution for the same. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? You need to use ajax of you want to stay on the same page. And you can then return a result indicating success or otherwise and update the DOM accordingly.

Comment: And you can remove the pointless `if(ModelState.IsValid)` line - your not posting back a model so `IsValid` will always be true.

Comment: Sorry if my question is not too clear, i tried to use ajax but there are n "Send Request" buttons in the same form. Thought using ajax was not the best method but i might be wrong in thinking so.

Comment: Ajax is your only option if you want _without reloading the form_

Answer (score 1):

I would return a bool from instead the ActionResult. Your JS (Jquery) code should look something like this:

```
$(btn).click(function(){
$(btn).attr("disabled", "disabled").val("Sending Request...");
$.ajax({
            url: '/yoururl',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { RequestId: '12345' },
            async: true,
            success: function(returnParameters) {
                $(btn).attr("disabled", "disabled").val("Request Sent");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
$(btn).removeAttr("disabled").val("Send Request"); // error, reset.
            }
        });
});
```

This will give three situations to the button:

1. Sending
2. Sent
3. Normal

I've also set the button to "disabled" to prevent more clicks incase it is in progress/the request was sent.